# Angular4 : jQuery + bootstrap.js + popper.js

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-4

coding the starter app from Bootstraps page with pure Angular4 is possible :

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/

But why re-invent the wheel ?

My question is :

1) what if I include at the bottom of index.html (and not in .angular-cli.json) these script tags for jquery + bootstrap.js :

```
<script src=".......jquery.min.js"></script>
​<script src=".......popper.min.js"></script>
<script src=".......bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If I only use jquery + popper only for simple UI manipulation (like responsiveness, dropdowns, datepicker, etc) and leave the 'heavy' stuff to Angular (typescript) would that create a conflict between Angular4 and jQuery at runtime ?

Comment: just have to careful. Zone.js monkey patches all browser events, so depending on your jquery code and/or plugins, it could cause performance issues. You could easily put a `{{ bindingExpression }}` to check how many times the digest cycle runs.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable info. I've read a bit about zone.js and it's clearer now that this is not a good approach, even if it works : https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/zones/